# Configure app (Slack in this case) to open with flag

Tags: applications

I have been able to open Slack from Terminal as follows:

```
'open -a /Applications/Slack.app/Contents/MacOS/Slack --args "--remote-debugging-port=' + port + '"'
```

Which allows me to do some cool things, but it's very fragile:

1. If the computer restarts, Slack re-opens without the flag
2. If I just `Command-Space` to launch Slack like a normal mortal, the `--remote-debugging-port` flag is not set.  I have to specifically open the `.sh` script I wrote to open with the flag.

You may have already guessed the question I want to ask: how do I configure Slack so that it by default opens and restarts with the given `--remote-debugging-port` flag?

Bonus: If changing Slack itself is required (hopefully not) any solution should obviously survive any Slack updates.  Thanks!

PS: If modifying the Slack.app to always start with a flag is absolutely NOT possible, the next step would (I think) be to write a mini-app which itself opens slack with the flag.  If this is the case some pointer in this direction would be great (but hope not needed)

PPS: Note that so far searching for `mac start app with flag` results lead to starting an app in Terminal; there is probably a term or phrase which I don't know which would lead me to an answer

(hopefully) Final Edit: The last-case resort probably has an answer here: [How can I set up a shell script as a wrapper to the main executable of an app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92797/how-can-i-set-up-a-shell-script-as-a-wrapper-to-the-main-executable-of-an-app)
though again having a mac system setting might be a better option here

Comment: Good question, have you done [any research](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how this can be achieved? Could you please [edit] your question to include what you've found so far, and why it didn't do what you wanted? This prevents that someone wastes their time in suggesting less helpful solutions.

Comment: I added a `PPS` - searching for `mac start app with flag` as stated leads to solutions that involve calling the app from Terminal (which I'm already doing).  So yes, I have searched but there's probably a key phrase for what I want to accomplish which if I knew would lead to an answer.